# Data obtaining check PUB/SUB pattern

Tags: python, zeromq, publish-subscribe, pyzmq

There is a server, that collects some data and then sends it to the client. I need to be sure that the client got the data sent by server. I thought PUB/SUB pattern here would be best choice, but I don't understand how to make check if client got the data? I heard something about reliable PUB/SUB, but there's no real example.

Any thought, suggestions, examples and help?

Simple publisher:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

server_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
server_socket.bind('tcp://*:5559')

while True:
    server_socket.send('message')
```

Simple subscriber:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

client_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
client_socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
client_socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5559')

while True:
    print client_socket.recv()
```

In this example i need to be shure that subscriber got 'message'.

Comment: Im probably going to show my ignorance of networking here, but isnt TCP a reliable communication protocol inherently, and the only way a subscriber wouldnt get the message is if they are not connected?

Comment: It is true, but i need to check if something is crashed and in that case i need to resend message.

F.e. client crashes for 20 sec, but server still is sending messages and when client wake up, a bunch of messages will be lost.

Comment: could you not just open a second port and listen to that for confirmations?

Answer (score 4):

In its general form, [pubsub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) is not appropriate for your use case.  One of the basic principles of pubsub is that publishers and subscribers are *decoupled*.  I.e. the publisher shouldn't be aware of its subscribers, and shouldn't be affected by them. There may be any number of subscribers, including none.

You seem to be requiring a single subscriber, which breaks that.

Comment: Thank you. Very clear answer

Answer (score 0):

The ZMQ guide talks about how the first few messages from a PUB socket will always be dropped, and how if you want the reliability you're talking about, you need the SUB end to send back a confirmation that it received each message.

You may want to consider using a PUSH/PULL connection instead. Replace your PUB with a PUSH and your SUB with a PULL. Maybe bind the PUSH end. See: [ZMQ PUSH/PULL](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Divide-and-Conquer)